# Import maven project to Eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu > pom.xml is disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I am trying to import a maven project to Eclipse 3.5 but when I do -

> import > existing maven projects > Browse my project >

pom.xml file is disabled, hence I can not select it and create a maven project.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have this project already imported in your workspace (i.e. in another working set?)

Comment: Nop, my workspace is all empty. I have set up a new eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if your workspace is the same folder your pom.xml is located in. Is this the case in your setup?